# React Native style Component using plain old JavaScript object

Tags: react-native

Hi I am new to React Native. When I read the doc about react native about how to custom the [style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html) of a component, I found that we can just using a javascript script object to set to the `style` prop of the `Component`. But they are provide a `Component` named `SheetSheet`, which have a method `create` that can define the styles. But, if we use the `StyleSheet` object to set the `Component` style, we need to first access the `SheetSheet` object and the access the property of that object(e.g `styles.redText`) to set the style. So what is the point using `SheetSheet`? If we want to group all the styles value together we can also define a custom object which can do exactly what `StyleSheet` is doing. So I don't understand why this component is here or if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`StyleSheet.create` is a performance-minded API. It makes sure that styles are generated once and referenced by ID in the future instead of being instantiated every time something changes like a normal object would.